# How to sort my array in custom sorting way

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

My output now

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [post_name] => brande
            [Product Name:] => Branded
            [Company Name] => "fas"
            [Company Url] => "dasdf"
            [Blog Topic] => "asdf"
            [Blog Url-1] => "asdf"
            [Reference Url] => "asdf"
            [Keywords] => "asdf"
            [Special Instructions] => "asdf"
        )
)
```

I want output will be

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [post_name] => brande
            [Product Name:] => Branded
            [Reference Url] => "asdf"
            [Blog Topic] => "asdf"
            [Keywords] => "asdf"
            [Special Instructions] => "asdf"
            [Company Name] => "fas"
            [Company Url] => "dasdf"            
            [Blog Url-1] => "asdf"            
        )
)
```

Comment: Could you tell us what you want? Or do we have to guess based on the arrays you show us? It could help if you show us what you have tried so far. A bit of code please.

Comment: sorting index by custom like second array

Comment: So there's no logic to the order of the array keys, but you just want them that way? The best way to do that is just to recreate the array with the keys in the 'custom' order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Information :

`$mCustomRowArray` is the array with the custom row. If you want `post_name` to be the last item you just change the position in that array.

`$mWrongArray` is an array of dummy data.

```
$mCustomRowArray= array(

    "post_name",
    "Product Name",
    "Reference Url",
    "Blog Topic",
    "Keywords",
    "Special Instructions",
    "Company Name",
    "Company Url",          
    "Blog Url-1",
);


$mWrongArray = array
(
    array(
            "post_name" => "post_name data",
            "Product Name" => "Product Name data",
            "Company Name" => "Company Name data",
            "Company Url" => "Company Url data",
            "Blog Topic" => "Blog Topic data",
            "Blog Url-1" => "Blog Url-1 data",
            "Reference Url" => "Reference Url data",
            "Keywords" => "Keywords data",
            "Special Instructions" => "Special Instructions data",
        ),

     array(
            "Keywords" => "Keywords data2",
            "Special Instructions" => "Special Instructions data2",
            "post_name" => "post_name data2",
            "Product Name" => "Product Name data2",
            "Company Name" => "Company Name data2",
            "Blog Url-1" => "Blog Url-1 data2",
            "Reference Url" => "Reference Url data2",
            "Company Url" => "Company Url data2",
            "Blog Topic" => "Blog Topic data2",

        ),
);


$mFinalArray = sortArrayWithCustomRowOf($mWrongArray, $mCustomRowArray);

print_r($mFinalArray);

function sortArrayWithCustomRowOf($mWrongArray, $mCustomRowArray){

    $mFinalArray = [];

    foreach($mWrongArray as $key => $current){


        foreach($mCustomRowArray as $mIndexArrayValue){

            $mTempArray[$mIndexArrayValue] = $current[$mIndexArrayValue];

        }

        $mFinalArray[] = $mTempArray;


    }


    return $mFinalArray;

}
```

> Output :

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [post_name] => post_name data
            [Product Name] => Product Name data
            [Reference Url] => Reference Url data
            [Blog Topic] => Blog Topic data
            [Keywords] => Keywords data
            [Special Instructions] => Special Instructions data
            [Company Name] => Company Name data
            [Company Url] => Company Url data
            [Blog Url-1] => Blog Url-1 data
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [post_name] => post_name data2
            [Product Name] => Product Name data2
            [Reference Url] => Reference Url data2
            [Blog Topic] => Blog Topic data2
            [Keywords] => Keywords data2
            [Special Instructions] => Special Instructions data2
            [Company Name] => Company Name data2
            [Company Url] => Company Url data2
            [Blog Url-1] => Blog Url-1 data2
        )

)
```